# Getting Post ID from slug during init

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug, plugin-posts-to-posts

I am trying to add a url rewrite rule that finds any posts that are connected to the current post (using Posts 2 Posts by scribu). It's tied into the WP Query object, so all I have to do is pass another variable "connected" => $post_id and it works. This is my rule that I am working with, but I don't have the post_id as a part of my url, so I can't get that via regex.

`add_rewrite_rule("cleats/([^/]+)/news", "index.php?tag=\$matches[1]", 'top');`

What really needs to happen if this is going to work is that I need to get the id based on the post slug via get_posts, but that seems like overkill to happen on every single init. Am I going down the right path, or is this not worth it?

---

What I want to happen is show only related news articles. For instance, I have a Manchester United page (custom post type of club) at /clubs/manchester-united. I want /clubs/manchester-united/news to show a listing of blog articles that are connected to that post. The way I am storing that information is with Posts 2 Posts, linking posts directly to that custom post. That keeps me from having to doubly maintain a list of tags that exactly match the custom post types that I have.

Where the query string for returning tags is as simple as ?tag=manchester-united, it works a little differently in my case. What I need is ?connected=45, where 45 is the post->ID of manchester-united. The regex in the rewrite rule above returns the slug "manchester-united", but that isn't enough information for my query. What I need to do is get the post->ID based on the "manchester-united" slug.

Is that hopefully a little clearer?

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your question. Can you give examples of the URLs you want and a description of what you expect each to do for you?

Comment: I changed the description above to include more detail.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a `WP_Rewrite` question, unless you want to include the post ID in the URL. I think the best way to solve this is, as you suggest, do a `get_posts()` query with your slug, and change the variables from there.

Of course you don't have to do this on every `init`, only do it when you are at a `clubs/[club_slug]/news/` page. So first create a rewrite rule that will set a special variable that you can check:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8421_init' );
function wpse8421_init()
{
    // Assuming `wpse8421_club` is the name of your custom post type
    add_rewrite_rule( 'clubs/([^/]+)/news/?$', 'index.php?wpse8421_club=$matches[1]&wpse8421_related_news=true', 'top' );
}
```

Add this query var to the public query vars so you can check for it:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse8421_query_vars' );
function wpse8421_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'wpse8421_related_news';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Then check for this extra variable, and if it is set, modify the query.

```
add_filter( 'request', 'wspe8421_request' );
function wpse8421_request( $query_vars )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'wpse8421_related_news', $query_vars ) ) {
        $club_posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'wpse8421_club',
            'name' => $query_vars['wpse8421_club'],
        ) );
        if ( $club_posts ) {
            $query_vars['connected'] = $club_posts[0]->ID;
            unset( $query_vars['wpse8421_club'] );
        }
    }
    return $query_vars;
}
```